# Адская многопоточность

Tags: java, concurrency

Ситуация такая: в пэкедже создается 6 энтити, которые в свою очередь являются потоками. Во время выполнения они заходят в `saveTelegram` (для того чтобы получить id из базы) и получается так, что пара энтити имеют одинаковый id, по этому часть не записывается в таблицу.

`Synchronized` не помогает, так как потоки не зависят друг от друга. Среди работающих вариантов решения проблемы были пауза `thread.sleep(1000)` и автоинкрементить id сразу в таблице не заходя в `saveTelegram` - но такое решение не подходит. Есть  ли еще идеи как решить данную проблему?

---

```
@Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    public Telegram saveTelegram(String ioNode, long userId,  
            String functionCode, byte[] payload) throws ProcessException {

        TelegramId histObj = persistenceManager.findTelegramId(); 
        Long entityId = histObj.getNextVal();//вытаскиваем id из таблицы TelegramId

        persistenceManager.updateTelegramId(histObj);

        TelegramHist telegramHist = createTelegram(entityId,
                ioNode, userId, payload, functionCode); 

        telegramHist = persistenceManager.saveOrUpdate(telegramHistoric);//записываем энтити в другую таблицу

        return telegramHist;
    }
```

так как данную проблему решает `thread.sleep(1000)` и две энтити ссылаются на один айдишник - я думаю что этот метод не потокобезопасный. И как решить данную проблему не знаю

Comment: Приведите свой код. Из описания вообще ничего непонятно. `Во время выполнения они заходят в методА (для того чтобы получить id из базы) и получается так, что пара энтити имеют одинаковый id` - это что значит? вы пишете что-то в базу и хотите получить созданный `id`? Тогда одинаковых `id` не может быть. `Synchronized не помогает, так как потоки не наследники одного класса и не зависят друг от друга` - это вообще что-то не связное, причем тут `synchronized` и наследование?

Comment: @iksuy `Во время выполнения они заходят в методА ....` это значит что нужно записать энтити в базу, и есть отдельная таблица в которой лежат id и вместо того чтобы записать так `entity1: id=1, entity2: id=2, entity3: id=3, entity4: id=4, entity5: id=5` пишет так `entity1: id=1, entity2: id=2, entity3: id=2, entity4: id=3,  entity5: id=4` 
а на счет наследования - думала что именно из-за не наследования потоки являются не зависимыми друг от друга и не обращают внимания на synchronized так как у каждого свой "ключ"

Comment: Это всё здорово, но пока вы не покажете код вам вряд ли кто-то поможет

Answer (score 0):

надо в самом методе **методА** сделать возможность некого лока для потоков.

Одним из простых и рабочих решениях может быть использование [try-lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) 
ReentrantLock.

```
public class MyClass { 

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public Integer getMethodA() { 
         lock.lock(); 
         try { 
            /// вот тут получение ID
            return ID;
         } finally {
            lock.unlock();
    }
```

Comment: @SenoirPomidor вы верите что это самый оптимальный вариант?

Comment: нет, не самый оптимальный, но вопрос не в оптимизации, а в решении доступа  к данным для разных потоков.

Comment: ReentrantLock уже пробовала, этот участок кода просто игнорируется. Даже делала из класса  `@Singleton` а над методом ставила аннотацию `@Lock(LockType.WRITE)`, но всё без толку

Comment: вы случайно над классом не поставили @Transactional? покажите лучше ваш код, добавиа в тело вопроса

Comment: нет нет, над классом только `@Singleton` и `@AccessTimeout`

Comment: все таки интересно что делаеют findTelegramId и getNextVal

Answer (score 0):

Ну да тут наследование вообще никакой роли не играет. Самое простое это сделать метод статическим и синхронизированным(static synchronized) и будет синхронизация.